# Mongoose: findOneAndUpdate pre hook not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've searched about this issue and all the solutions that I've found didn't actually work. I'm currently using this function to encrypt the password before storing in the database but even though the values are being changed when logging `this`, the password isn't stored like it was changed in the function.

```
UserSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next) {
  const update = this.getUpdate();
  if (!_.isEmpty(update.password)) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
      bcrypt.hash(update.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
        this.getUpdate().password = hash;
        next();
      })
    })
  }
  next();
});
```

I've also tried to change the value of `this._update.password` instead but it didn't work either. I've also tried using `$set` or even using a `post` hook but none of them helped either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested this locally with:

```
var result = Author.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: <some id> }, { password: '111' }).exec()
```

and this `pre` hook:

```
AuthorSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next) {
  this._update.password = 'BBB'
  next();
});
```

Password was saved as `BBB`

Author schema has a password field which is `type: String`

I am on **3.6.5**

In your bcrypt case you have also an extra `next()` without `else` which is messing you up ... should be:

```
UserSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next) {
  const update = this.getUpdate();
  if (!_.isEmpty(update.password)) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
      bcrypt.hash(update.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
        this.getUpdate().password = hash;
        next();
      })
    })
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Comment: It does work when not using the bcrypt method. Even though the value of `this._update.password` is changed to the hash value, it doesn't actually change it when being stored in the database.

Comment: Tested with bcrypt. See the update. Your 2nd `next()` was firing so it needs to be in `else`

Answer (score 1):

```
user.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next){
    const user=this.getUpdate().$set;
    if(!user.password){
      next();
    }
    else{
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function (err, hash) {
          if (err) {
            return next(err);
          }
          user.password = hash;
           next();
        });
    });
  }
})
```