# How to embed bcrypt into mongoose API call?

Tags: authentication, mongoose, passwords, mongoose-schema, bcrypt

### Setup

I am doing web site authorization, and want to embed best practices into it, while keeping code clean and readible. For now I have classic code like this:

```
let foundUser = await userModel.findOne({ email: recievedEmail });
if(!foundUser)
    error("not authorized!");
const isPasswordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(recievedPassword, foundUser.password);
if(!isPasswordMatch)
    error("not authorized!");
foundUser.update({ $set: { lastLogin: new Date() }, $push: { myEvents: authEvent } });
foundUser.save();
success("authorized OK!");
```

Meanwhile, I've asked a question on the [best mongoose command to perform auth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55304188/1976993), and we've forged up the following "auth-check-and-update" command, in an "atomic" manner:

```
const foundUser = await userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { email: recievedEmail, password: recievedPassword },
    { $set: { lastLogin: new Date() }, $push: { myEvents: authEvent } }
);
if(foundUser)
    success("authorized OK!");
else
    error("not authorized!");
```

Idea here is obvious - if a user *with matching email and password is found* then user is *considered as authorized*, and its *last login timestamp is updated* (simultaneously).

---

### Problem

To combine best practices from the two above, I need somehow to embed `bcrypt.compare()` call inside `findOneAndUpdate()` call. That is tricky to do, because I cannot just "compare hashed passwords"; bcrypt just works differently from simple hashes (like sha or md5): [For security reasons it returns different hashes every time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39198006/1976993). (Answers in the link explains "why and how").

---

### Solution Attempt

I've looked into [`mongoose-bcrypt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-bcrypt) package: it is utilizing `Schema.pre()` functionality:

```
 schema.pre('update', preUpdate);
 schema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', preUpdate);
```

To get the idea, please, take a look at [`mongoose-bcrypt\index.js`](https://github.com/proswdev/mongoose-bcrypt/blob/master/index.js#L112-L143).
You will see, that `preUpdate` affects only creating new user (..`andUpdate` part), but not actual checking (`findOne`.. part). So this plugin could fit for implementing "user registration" / "change password". But it can't work for authorization in the proposed way.

---

### Question

How would you "combine" `bcrypt.compare()` and `userModel.findOneAndUpdate()` calls under such circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

What about compare password in UserModel like this

```
// method to compare password input to password saved in database
UserModel.methods.isValidPassword = async function(password){
    const user = this;
    const compare = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    return compare;
}
```

And inside your auth or passport (i am using passport) do something like this

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    (username, password, done) => {
        // change your query here with findOneAndUpdate
        User.findOne({ username: username }, (err, user) => {
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) {

                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
            }
            if (!user.isValidPassword(password)) {

                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));
```

Comment: You shound **not** call `isValidPassword`, because you **must** check user password **only inside** `findOneAndUpdate`: if a user is returned then its name and pasword **alredy matched**! Checking before call is too early. checking after call is too late. How to check bcrypted password just **inside** `findOneAndUpdate`?

Comment: That is a bit advanced question, sorry I formed it badly. (I alredy have a working authorisation code, similar to that you wrote)

Comment: I've edited question to better fit what exactly I wanted.

Comment: what about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52482992/mongoose-findoneandupdate-pre-hook-not-working

Comment: This calls bcrypt.hash() but I need bcrypt.compare ()

Comment: ok, i think you can call bcrypt.compare() instead of bcrypt.hash()

Comment: Sure thing, that's exactly what I want to do, but don't know where to get parameters for compare